# Facebook share The showing image is not the image set in og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

In my PDP(product display page),i set og:image as my product image,however,in share facebook page,the sharing img is not what I expected in og:image
Don't know why
I have tried my URL:h ttp://www.halfords.com/cycling/helmets/kids-helmets/halfords-boys-bike-helmet-50-54cm in facebook debug page:h ttps://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
the below is the screenshot in facebook debug page.
green arrow pointed is expected,however,it shows the red arrow pointed

[image]

Thanks very much for the kind guy to give me some suggestion.[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug complains about a circular redirect path, so you’ll need to fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the web page you're developing isn't tested/located on a local server (like WAMP/MAMP etc.). Facebook might not necessarily get every property exactly right. Try testing it live.

Comment: of course,it is not tested/located URL,it is:http://www.halfords.com/cycling/helmets/kids-helmets/halfords-boys-bike-helmet-50-54cm,however,og:image can not control the showing image,the Facebook share engine seems to get the biggest size image on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Check your image size is at least 200x200 pixels (do not use a thumbnails). Then re-scrape your image with facebook's [debugger tool](http://developer.facebook.com/debug/tools)