# Facebook sharer is not working as expcted

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have inserted the OG meta tags in my pages and also have provided a simple link to help users share the contents on the Facebook using the

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[the-urlencoded-link-to-my-page]
```

link. But I have two problems:

1. When attempting to share the content for the first time, the
   Facebook sharer page only displays a preview box which only contains
   the name of the site, and makes me use the Facebook's [Object
   Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) to
   fetch the meta tags. How can I automate this process?
2. And secondly, while the Object Debugger report says that it has
   found the `og:url`, `og:type`, `og:title`, `og:locale`,
   `og:image:width`, `og:image:height`, `og:image` and the
   `og:description` raw tags on the page, but the image doesn't get
   displayed in neither the preview box of the page nor on the shared
   status. What I have missed? What's wrong?

To make things clear, sharing on google+ works perfectly (the image gets displayed, the title and the descriptions are in place.)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update 2) No errors/warnings about the image in debug tool? Also, try https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the reply :) Actually, there is _no_ errors/warnings at all! But as I've stated, even in Object Debugger, despite having the image URL detected accurately, but the image doesn't get displayed even in that very page! And about the pre-caching, I already have the proper `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`!

Comment: Can you give us the URL to a live example?

Comment: what is the size of image (minimum is 200x200 px) -  and can you post the og meta tags

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529962/facebook-share-the-showing-image-is-not-the-image-set-in-ogimage